# Trying to use c++ qsort with an inline function

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, qsort

I am trying to create an inline function for a comparer to qsort - something like this:

```
function<int(int,int)> comparesort = [smarkers, emarkers, strSearch] (int *arg1, int *arg2) { return 0; };
qsort(sortptrs, nKeywords, sizeof(int), comparesort);
```

It's giving me this error

IntelliSense: no suitable conversion function from "std::tr1::function" to "int (__cdecl *)(const void *, const void *)" exists

ok - I changed it to this

```
auto comparesort = [sortptrs, smarkers, emarkers, strSearch] (int arg1, int arg2)
{
    int a = 0;
    .
    .
    .
    return a;
};

std::sort(sortptrs, sortptrs + nKeywords, comparesort);
```

and it's giving an error:

error C3499: a lambda that has been specified to have a void return type cannot return a value

[edit on 7/30 3:55 pm]

I actually needed a pointer sort - I've got an array of start and end bytes of words (found in a string passed in from VB.Net managed code).  I also have a pointer-array that contains "1,2,3..." and I needed to sort the pointer.

Didn't seem I could do that with std::sort so I implemented my own shell sort...

Comment: `qsort`?! What about using `std::sort`?

Comment: @BoPersson - I tried std::sort - having a problem with the return type of the function

Answer (score 12):

The signature of `qsort` takes a function pointer of type `int(*)(const void*, const void*)`. You are trying to give it a `function<int(int, int)>`, which is not a function pointer, but an object encapsulating something (might be a function ptr, might be a functor) which is callable as `int(int, int)` (note that it wouldn't have the right signature, even if it was a function pointer).

`qsort` is a basically a legacy function for backward compatibility with c.
In c++ I would strongly suggest forgetting about it and using `std::sort` instead:

```
auto comparesort = [smarkers, emarkers, strSearch] (const  int& arg1, const int& arg2) { return false; }; 
//directly store the lambda, avoiding the overhead of creating a `function<...>`
std::sort(sortptrs, sortptrs + nKeywords, comparesort);
```

Comment: Ok - I posted more details up in the OP

Comment: @szlamany: Your lambda isn't correct. For lambdas with more then one line you need to explicitely mention the return type (Which should be `bool` not `int` for `std::sort`).

Comment: If it's bool then it's not the old -1/0/1 that regular comparer use.  What is the TRUE for and what is the FALSE for?  And how would I actually declare the lambda - I'm totally new to C++ here so the syntax is killing me!  Thanks!

Comment: Ok - this now gets me past the RETURN DATATYPE issue I added: -> bool now it is "auto comparesort = [sortptrs, smarkers, emarkers, strSearch] (int arg1, int arg2) -> bool"

Comment: I actually needed a pointer sort - I've got an array of start and end bytes of words (found in a string passed in from VB.Net managed code).  I also have a pointer-array that contains "1,2,3..." and I needed to sort the pointer.  Didn't seem I could do that with std::sort so I implemented my own shell sort...

Comment: Just thought I would pass this benchmark along. I am sorting a small array (128 elements of uint16_t) in firmware on an ARM Cortex M3.  std::sort() takes 680 microseconds and qsort() takes 1790 microseconds (compiled with gcc -O3). So std::sort is indeed much more efficient, probably due to inlining of the comparison function.

Answer (score 5):

`qsort` is the old C API that takes a function pointer directly. You can't use it with anything else such as lambdas. Instead, use `std::sort`.

Comment: Almost right - it will take a non-capturing lambda too. Still, `std::sort` is more efficient.

Comment: @msalters - I'm having a hard time getting the return type of the lamdba function working - I posted more code up top

Comment: @szlamany: Your lambda is capturing. A non-capturing lambda starts with `[]`, an empty capture list.